# Am I freeing memory properly in this C program?

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing a small program that reads multiple input lines from the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXINPUT 256
#define MAXLINES 32

/* Reads at most maxLines inputs from stdin. Returns number of lines. */
int readlines(char** buffer, int maxLines, size_t maxInput);
/* Gets input from stdin with maxInput as the limit. Returns size of string. Terminates at newline. */
int getstdline(char* buffer, int maxInput);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char** buffer = malloc((sizeof buffer[0]) * MAXLINES);
    int numlines = readlines(buffer, MAXLINES, MAXINPUT);

    /* free memory that was allocated for each str */
    for(int i = 0; i < numlines; ++i) {
        free(*(buffer++));
    }
    /* free memory that was allocated to hold all the strings */
    free(buffer);
}

int readlines(char** buffer, int maxLines, size_t maxInput) {
    int linecount = 0;

    while(maxLines--) {
        char* tmp = malloc(maxInput);
        /* if empty string, exit loop */
        if(getstdline(tmp, maxInput) <= 0) {
            free(tmp);
            break;
        }

        *buffer = tmp;
        ++linecount;
        ++buffer;

    }
    return linecount;
}
```

My question is regarding the call to `malloc()` in `readlines(char**,int,size_t)`. I obviously can't `free()` the memory within the function so to free it at the end of the program, I tried to loop through the array of `char*` and free them individually.  I then also free `char** buffer` in `main()` because it was also allocated using `malloc()`.

Looping through each of them gives me the error :

```
object was probably modified after being freed.
```

Freeing `char** buffer` at the end **works fine**.

So it seems there is a concept of dynamic memory I am not quite understanding. Why is this happening and what would be the correct way to handle memory in this specific program?

Comment: `char** buffer = malloc(MAXLINES);` should probably be `char** buffer = malloc(MAXLINES * sizeof buffer[0]);`. Poor `malloc()` can't read your mind.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Oops! Fixed it.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I'm guessing that wasn't supposed to be the fix. The problem still persists.

Comment: That was one of the problems. "The fix" is doing this **and** what the answer suggested. This is also a problem, it wouldn't work correctly without my comment either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the buffer pointer by running `buffer++` so when you call `free(buffer)` you are passing in the wrong pointer.  You can rewrite your loop to not modify that pointer.